Delete duplicate vectors from command line
I have one vector layer called "trails" and another called "roads."
There are vectors with identical geometry, and I want to delete any vectors in the trails layer with identical geometry in the roads layer. Both are GeoPackages but of course can be converted to other formats as needed.
I am able to do this with qgis by using the Select by location function using equal in the Processing Toolbox and then deleting the selected vectors. However, I am trying to accomplish this in the command line (Ubuntu), and since the selection is made in the GUI, I can't run it as a qgis_process command.
If I understand correctly, duplicates can be deleted with GRASS, but it requires the vectors to be in the same vector layer, which complicates things a great deal since they will also need to be separated.
While I've started experimenting with SQL statements using ogrinfo, I've found it to be quite complex and slow to achieve the same results. Given that the task at hand is fundamentally simple, I'm reaching out to this knowledgeable community to see if anyone has a more efficient method to accomplish this.
